# replace a for loop with a table reshape and vector calculation in R?

Tags: r

I have a dataset where individual trees have diameter measurements over multiple time points. The dataframe is in "long format" with one column for tree ID, one for date and one for diameter. Here is code to generate analogous data in R.

```
#generate example data frame.
date <- c(1999, 2001, 2004)
dia  <- c(12, 13, 14)
N.tree <- 1000
tree.ID <- paste0('tree_',1:N.tree)

data.list <- list()
for(i in 1:length(tree.ID)){
  data.list[[i]] <- data.frame(tree.ID[i],date,dia)
}
dat <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, data.list))
colnames(dat) <- c('tree.ID','date','dia')
dat$tree.ID <- as.character(dat$tree.ID)
```

I want to get the first and last observation of each unique tree, when those observations were taken, and the corresponding diameters at the beginning and end into a table in "wide" format. I am currently doing this with a for-loop and it is painfully slow, example here that generates the output I want.

```
#current (slow) calculation.
growth.dat <- list()
for(i in 1:length(unique(dat$tree.ID))){
  z <- dat[dat$tree.ID == unique(dat$tree.ID)[i],]
  t1 <- min(z$date)
  t2 <- max(z$date)
  d1 <- z[z$date == t1,]$dia
  d2 <- z[z$date == t2,]$dia
  out <- c(unique(dat$tree.ID)[i],t1,t2,d1,d2)
  growth.dat[[i]] <- out
}
growth.dat <- data.frame(do.call(rbind, growth.dat))
colnames(growth.dat) <- c('tree.ID','t1','t2','d1','d2')
```

I know this is bad R practice for exactly this reason- for-loops are slow in R. How can I speed this up? Also, I want to emphasize that my actual data are a bit messier than the example above. Some trees have two time points, some have 9, some have missing data in the diameter field for certain dates. Solutions in base R preferred, but I'll take what works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, we can select `min` and `max` `date` for each `tree.ID` along with corresponding `dia` values.

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>%
  group_by(tree.ID) %>%
  summarise(t1 = min(date), t2 = max(date), 
            d1 = dia[which.max(date == t1)], d2 = dia[which.max(date == t2)]) %>%
  arrange(as.integer(sub(".*_", "", tree.ID)))


# A tibble: 1,000 x 5
#   tree.ID    t1    t2    d1    d2
#   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 tree_1   1999  2004    12    14
# 2 tree_2   1999  2004    12    14
# 3 tree_3   1999  2004    12    14
# 4 tree_4   1999  2004    12    14
# 5 tree_5   1999  2004    12    14
# 6 tree_6   1999  2004    12    14
# 7 tree_7   1999  2004    12    14
# 8 tree_8   1999  2004    12    14
# 9 tree_9   1999  2004    12    14
#10 tree_10  1999  2004    12    14
# … with 990 more rows
```

---

Using `aggregate`, we can get first and last value for each `tree.ID`.

```
do.call(data.frame, aggregate(cbind(date, dia)~tree.ID, dat, 
                    function(x) c(x[1], x[length(x)]))
```

Comment: Thanks. How does `first` know to select the diameter associated with the first date? In some cases I have "shrinking" trees and its not clear if this is a min/max or somehow magically linked to the first call to date, implying the output of `first` is dependent on how many calls to `first` have been made.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you the first time (although answer was the same for this dataset). I have updated the answer to include corresponding `dia`. Can you check now?

Comment: Thanks. I think I am going to go with your initial `aggregate` response in base R. The confusing part however is that the output of the `aggregate` call is dataframe, but it claims to only have 3 columns when I do an `nrow()` call, instead of 5. Any idea whats up and how to fix?

Comment: It returns a matrix actually. I have updated the answer.